# Alternative to &#x2610; and &#x2612; on Android (Samsung Tab 2) browser

Tags: android, browser, unicode, samsung-mobile

Internet browser I have installed (by default) on my Samsung Tab2 does not display ☐`&#x2610;` and ☒`&#x2612;` characters properly. What are alternative solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fonts on Android do not contain these characters, so your options seem to be:

1. Use a downloadable font, via `@font-face`. It can be difficult to find a font suitable for this, since most free fonts are rather limited in their character coverage. Among the relatively few fonts that contain these characters (cf. to [font coverage info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2610/fontsupport.htm) at Fileformat.info), DejaVu Sans might be suitable (though somewhat large in file size, about 668 kilobytes).
2. Use images. A bit dull these days, but a working solution. In this case, create images that are several times larger than expected font size and scale them down to match the font size, using e.g. `width: 0.6em` for the images.
3. Use a no-break space and the multiplication sign “×” and put, with CSS, them into small boxes with borders. Sample code below. This seems to be the best approach here.

   ```
   <style>
   .box {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: baseline;
     line-height: 0.6;
     border: solid 0.08em;
     width: 0.6em;
     height: 0.6em;
     text-align: center;
     font-weight: bold;
   }
   </style>
   <span class=box>&nbsp;</span>
   <span class=box>&times;</span>
   ```