# Why does this arrow appear blue on tablets?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am using the following HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>This arrow here: <span><a href="#">&#8617;</a></span></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my `style.css`:

```
span > a {
    color: #F5413C;
}
```

---

On Firefox 31 (Windows 8), it displays just fine:

[image]

However, on my tablet (Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 2014) the arrow appears as a thick blue:

[image]

---

How do I fix this? Can this be fixed? Is there, somewhere, a list of ASCII characters that display fine across all platforms?

Unfortunately, I can't find developer tools on Chrome on the tablet, so I can't diagnose this problem.

Comment: It's the unicode character that's being shown as an image. As far as I know, there's nothing you can do to change the color of it.

Comment: Read this [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12825609/1577396) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14567146/1577396).

Comment: So, on my computer, the character displays as I want it to be displayed (using the Segoe UI font). Is there a way to extract the character as an SVG from the font and use that on the page without having to make the page download the entire font?

Answer (score 1):

The arrow is rendered in an emoji font, which likely exists on the tablet but does not exist on your desktop. Or the emoji font is the only font on the tablet that contains this character at all, while your desktop has a wider variety of fonts which contain this glyph in a "more traditional" form and are chosen before any emoji font.

The solution is to set the font explicitly to a font which shows the character in the way you desire, and which also exists on the tablet. If the tablet doesn't have any font that contains this character other than the one you're seeing, there's not much you can do besides using an image instead.

Comment: Presumably adding (`sans-`)`serif` as the last option would prevent it ever rendering as emoji?

Comment: I don't know about that, but would think that's not the case. It depends on what fallback strategies the browser has; most browsers would rather render a character "out of style" than not at all.

Comment: Is there a way to perhaps only load the character into HTML rather than having to download a whole font for that single character?

Comment: @Nikhik You could generate a font which only contains that single character. I'm sure there are online generators for this sort of thing.